# Implementing shift operation in sesam

Tags: sesam

**I have the below entity**

**Source Data**

```
{
  "$ids": [
    "~:xyz:431-35033464"
  ],
  "_deleted": false,
  "_hash": "8717270a4d9d367022ae1aac1c0796be",
  "_id": "mips-company:431-35033464",
  "_previous": 11461,
  "_ts": 1561267134181856,
  "_updated": 13577,
  "xyz:CompanyId": 12345678,
  "xyz:CompanyName": "Zoouid",
  "xyz:CompanyNo": "ZD",
  "xyz:ProjectId": 143,
  "rdf:type": "~:xyz:Company"
}
```

Whats needed is before this data is populated to GCP hosted sql instance an id property (column which is an INT that is 32bit, and when we combine the two properties we will increase it to BIGINT which is 64 bits), to be created using shift operation  to have a combination of ProjectId and CompanyId ,

earlier 
I have tried  to  concatenate and convert back to integer but get an error with out of range, so the system owner wants shift operation and since we do not have that in sesam he he suggested to use multiply and exponential to implement ( not sure if it really solves the issue). ie (143 * 2^32 + 12345678)  we still exceed the range.

**output is as below-**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "mips-company:431-35033464",
    "company-xyz:comp_number": "ZD",
    "company-xyz:id": 614192669006,
    "company-xyz:name": "Zoouid",
    "company-xyz:project_id": 143
  }
]
```

And i still get error-

> "original_error_message": "sqlalchemy.exc.DataError:
>   (mysql.connector.errors.DataError) 1264 (22003): Out of range value
>   for column 'id' at row 1 [SQL: 'INSERT INTO company (id, comp_number,
>   name, project_id``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see your new ID value (614192669006) should fit well within a big int. Perhaps the database column is still an int?